# Is there a simple way to get the time difference at millisecond level in between 2 Kubernetes pods?

Tags: kubernetes

This is my scenario:
I have 2 pods running on a Kubernetes cluster. What I want to see is if there is any time difference(at millisecond level) in between the 2 pods.
Is there a simple way to get the time difference at millisecond level in between 2 pods?

Thanks